# How to convert row names into a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following excel dataset:

```
         ($/bbl)      ($/bbl)      ($/bbl)
         crude_petro  crude_brent  crude_dubai
1960M01  1.63         1.63         1.63
1960M02  1.63         1.63         1.63
1960M03  1.63         1.63         1.63
```

What I want to do is to convert the row names `crude_petro, crude_brent, crude_dubai`
into columns such that in the format like this:

**EDIT 2**

```
    unit        commodity       price    date
0   ($/bbl)     crude_petro     1.63     1960M01
1   ($/bbl)     crude_brent     1.63     1960M01
2   ($/bbl)     crude_dubai     1.63     1960M01
```

How can I achieve this using pandas?

**EDIT**:
This is how I am reading the excel to possibly parse those values

```
df = pd.read_excel(local_path, sheet_name='Monthly Prices', engine='openpyxl', skiprows=5, usecols="B:BT")
```

**EDIT 3:**
In my final column, the data is generating extra columns that doesn't exist on my spreadsheet(source) which is associated with NaN values. For example, the commodity SILVER is outputting 'SILVER.1', 'SILVER.2', etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas-melt) + [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-index):

```
new_df = (
    df.melt(ignore_index=False, var_name=['unit', 'commodity'])
        .sort_index()
        .rename_axis('Date')
        .reset_index()
)
```

`new_df`:

```
      Date     unit    commodity  value
0  1960M01  ($/bbl)  crude_petro   1.63
1  1960M01  ($/bbl)  crude_brent   1.63
2  1960M01  ($/bbl)  crude_dubai   1.63
3  1960M02  ($/bbl)  crude_petro   1.63
4  1960M02  ($/bbl)  crude_brent   1.63
5  1960M02  ($/bbl)  crude_dubai   1.63
6  1960M03  ($/bbl)  crude_petro   1.63
7  1960M03  ($/bbl)  crude_brent   1.63
8  1960M03  ($/bbl)  crude_dubai   1.63
```

---

Sample Frame Used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    ('($/bbl)', 'crude_petro'): {'1960M01': 1.63, '1960M02': 1.63,
                                 '1960M03': 1.63},
    ('($/bbl)', 'crude_brent'): {'1960M01': 1.63, '1960M02': 1.63,
                                 '1960M03': 1.63},
    ('($/bbl)', 'crude_dubai'): {'1960M01': 1.63, '1960M02': 1.63,
                                 '1960M03': 1.63}
})
```

`df`:

```
            ($/bbl)                        
        crude_petro crude_brent crude_dubai
1960M01        1.63        1.63        1.63
1960M02        1.63        1.63        1.63
1960M03        1.63        1.63        1.63
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding! I am getting an IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2. The spreadsheet has other underlying information that I didn't add to this post so please see the edited version of how I am reading the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Add `header=[0, 1]` to `read_excel` to read the data in with a multi index?

Comment: That did it. Appreciate all the help!

Comment: Forgot to mention that I want to include the first row of dates mapped to this new dataset. Do I need to make the changes in the melt() to accomplish this? Please see edited dataframe

Comment: You're right. I updated my post for clarity. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I want all the dates

Comment: Perfect. I have ways to go in learning pandas but you have helped immensely. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Hey Henry, can you look at my most recent edit? The read_excel operation appears to be reading columns that don't exist with an NaN value. Would you happen to know how I can go around this?

Comment: I found out that openpyxl was giving me issues. I was able to resolve this by replacing 'engine=openpyxl' to 'engine=xlrd'